# Access Policy not provisioning resource Accounts to the User

Tags: identity, identity-management, oim, identitymanager

I have a role based access policy configured in OIM PS3 environment, Whenever user is provisioned Role 'A' user is entitled to get AD account and viceversa. But this is not happening even after running evaluate user policies job multiple time.

In database when I am checking on Role assignment if the `USER_PROVISIONING_ATTRS.POLICY_EVAL_NEEDED` is `1` then its showing it right for that user but its not provisioning the accounts to user.

scheduler is returning success all the time.

Post completing the scheduler the `USER_PROVISIONING_ATTRS.POLICY_EVAL_NEEDED` is `0` and `USER_PROVISIONING_ATTRS.POLICY_EVAL_IN_PROGRESS` is `0`.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: At any time the 'Evaluate User Policies' scheduler had been disabled/enabled?

Comment: @varpekv No, but earlier it was stuck for few users on bulk load

Comment: Have you interrupted the scheduled job at that time?

Comment: @varpekv No but as it was taking longer time I scheduled it to run manually instead of periodic. And then for long time we did not used it, but for those users it still not getting evaluated till now. :(

Comment: I was faced similar issue and it was resolved by restarting the OIM server. Can you try this and let me know.

Comment: No restarting OIM did not resolve it for me :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128809/discussion-between-varpekv-and-chaitanya-kurdukar).

Comment: Is there any error in oim_server1-dignostic.log file

Comment: No errors in the logs but the access policy needs eval in db remains 1 for these users

Comment: Could you please give the values set in your environment for below system properties  'Allows linking of access policies to reconciled and bulk loaded accounts' and 'Allows access policy based provisioning of multiple instances of a resource'

Comment: Could you please also check the event handlers related to provisioning on the particular day.

Comment: @varpekv Values set in My environment for below system properties `Allows linking of access policies to reconciled and bulk loaded accounts`  and `Allows access policy based provisioning of multiple instances of a resource`  has value `FALSE`

Comment: It seems all configurations looks correct, I don't know why it still not working.

Comment: You should also check the process form attached in access policy,if the information is correct and it is saved properly.

Comment: @PriyaSharma yes it is there and saved properly :)

Comment: I am having the same issue

Comment: Facing same issue. If anyone got solution, please let me know?

Comment: Did you check to see if there was an organization conflict? (Is Ad published to the user?)

Comment: Yes AD is published to the Organization user currently in